# ome problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.ktech:xpira:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[WARNING]  
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.ktech:xpira:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar -> duplicate declarati
```

Comment: What build tool are you using and what is in your build file?

Comment: Your error message seems to be cut, looks like you have duplicate declaration for mysql connector